# Achieving low train error for exponential response?

Tags: regression

I'm trying to fit an ML model with *perfect information* to predict an exponentially distributed response without getting exponentially distributed error...

Also, this situation is special for a few of reasons:

1. I've tried fitting $M(x)\approx log(y)$, *unfortunately it actually degraded performance* (in the original domain).
2. **I'm positive that the response variable is 100% determined by the inputs, since we are trying to mimic physical simulation code which takes the same inputs.**
3. **Despite point 2, the best error I can get is still on the order of MAE$\approx$ 1.2e+9** (*the response variable itself has mean=1.334e+09 & SD=1.35676394551e+11*).

Is it possible to somehow get low train error (i.e. in *absolute*, rather than relative terms) given perfect information?